# Are IShellWindows and IWebBrowser2 objects always out of process?

Tags: c++, shell, winapi

I've been experimenting with instantiating `CLSID_ShellWindows`, and so far I've had luck only when using `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER`.  Even when I try creating it from within Explorer itself (after setting a hook and injecting a DLL), it works only when instantiated as an out-of-process object.

I was wondering if it's ever possible to obtain an in-process version of the shell windows and their related objects.  Like for example, if you implement a browser helper object or Explorer toolband, and you obtain an `IWebBrowser2` object/interface using the site pointer provided through `SetSite`, will that be an in-process object, or is that out of process as well?

Comment: It makes sense for a `ShellWindows` object to be out-of-process, but a BHO/ExplorerBand runs in the same process as the browser/explorer, so it doesn't make sense for the `IWebBrowser2` it provides to the BHO/band to be an out-of-process object.

Comment: It's because this CLSID is registered for LocalServer only. If you run inprocess with explorer, you can test this: https://pastebin.com/raw/vBnYSyyP (don't know if it works, I can't test it right now)

Comment: @SimonMourier I tried your code (though specifying `CLSCTX_INPROC`).  Those calls succeeded, but the resulting Shell Windows object did not reflect the actual shell windows that were present.  It seemed to be just an empty object.